# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property - hibernate error maven annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am working on a test project to learn hibernate, unfortunately I am getting this error and have looked at other similar errors, but following them didn't solve my problem. I am still getting this error.

Can someone check what is going wrong, I would really appreciate to know what is my mistake.

The my model classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="survey")
public class Survey implements java.io.Serializable{

    /**
    * 
    */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "survey_id")
private Long _id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "survey")
private List<Question> _questions ;

@Column(name="name")
private String _name;

public Survey() {
    super();
}

public Survey(Long id, List<Question> questions, String name) {
    super();
    _id = id;
    _questions = questions;
    _name = name;

    Assert.notNull(_id, "_id cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_questions, "_questions cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_name, "_name cannot be null");
}

public Long getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    _id = id;
}


public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    return _questions;
}

public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
    _questions = questions;
}


public String getName() {
    return _name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    _name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Survey [_id=" + _id + ", _questions=" + _questions + ", _name="
            + _name + "]";
}
```

}

This is the second model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class Question implements java.io.Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long _id;

@Column(name = "label")
private String _label;

@Column(name="type")
private QuestionType _type;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="survey_id")
private Survey _survey;

public Question() {
}

public Question(final Long id, final String label, final QuestionType type, final Survey survey,final Long surveyId) {
    _id = id;
    _label = label;
    _type = type;
    _survey = survey;

    Assert.notNull(_id, "_id cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_label, "_label cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_type, "_type cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(_survey, "_survey cannot be null");
}

public Long getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    _id = id;
}


public String getLabel() {
    return _label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    _label = label;
}


public QuestionType getType() {
    return _type;
}

public void setType(QuestionType type) {
    _type = type;
}

public Survey getSurvey() {
    return _survey;
}

public void setSurvey(Survey survey) {
    _survey = survey;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Question [_id=" + _id + ", _label=" + _label + ", _type="
            + _type + "]";
}
```

}

This is my main:

```
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Hibernate one to many (Annotation)");
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    Survey survey = new Survey();
    survey.setName("Ice Cream final");
    session.save(survey);

    Question question1 = new Question();
    question1.setLabel("Whats your favorite Ice Cream");
    question1.setType(QuestionType.TEXT);
    question1.setSurvey(survey);
    survey.getQuestions().add(question1);
    session.save(question1);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("Done");

}
```

This is my hibernate util class:

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
```

}

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/survey</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="xxxxx.Survey" />
    <mapping class="xxxxx.Question" />
</session-factory>
```

Error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an     unknown target entity property: xxxx.model.Question.Survey in xxxx.model.Survey._questions
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at xxxx.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:16)
at xxxx.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
at xxxx.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: xxxx.model.Question.SurveyModel in xxxx.model.Survey._questions
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:655)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:619)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1221)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:383)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1377)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
at xxxx.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
... 2 more
```

Comment: where is SurveyModel? please edit the question and include it.

Comment: @zerocool I was just trying to change the class name and test if it works, it was a typo I have replaced it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "survey")
private List<Question> _questions ;
```

So you're telling Hibernate: go look at the `Question.survey` field to know how this association is mapped.

Is there a field named `survey` in Question? No there isn't. The field is named `_survey`.

Please please please, make your code readable and your life easier, and respect the Java naming conventions. Variables don't start with underscores. You really really don't want every JPQL/HQL query of your app to have underscores everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I thought that survey will be the class name and was trying out things, I also reffered other threads with similar isssue. After Changing survey to _survey that error is resolved I am currently getting this error. Can you please guide me on this:

Comment: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Comment: Post another question, with the code and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Mapped By** must be getter name of child class.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "survey")
private List<Question> _questions ;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="survey_id")
private Survey survey;
```

Comment: If it had to be the getter name of the child class, the OP's code would work fine. It has to be the name of the annotated field or property of the child class. Here, the field is annotated, and the field name is `_survey`.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm agree with you. Mapped By name is a logical name. You can use what ever you need.You can use proprty name or field name

Comment: No, you can't. If the field is annotated, then it must be the field name. If the property is annotated, then it must be the property name.

Answer (score 0):

In Question Entity class you must use the same name for field you use in mappedBy in Survey class.So:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "survey")
private List<Question> _questions ;

@JoinColumn(name="survey_id")
private Survey survey;
```